# Find the minimun element of a dictionary when min is eqal for all values python

Tags: python

I have this

```
my_dict = {'x':500, 'y':500, 'z': 500}
min_s=min(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)
```

when I print the `min_s`, it arbitrary print either `x` or `y` or `z`, but I want to just print the first key meaning `x`. How can I do this?

Also, how can I check if all values are the same ?

Thanks

Comment: Dicts are unordered in something vresions of python, which are you using?

Comment: You want the first key in alphabetic order or in the order you add them to the dict? Take a look at the [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: in the same way that I add them to the dictionary

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please [mark it as 'accepted’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries in python are not (insertion) ordered, the order will basically follow whatever hash function the dictionary is using for your keys, and that can change everytime.

For (insertion) order preserving dictionaries you should use `collections.OrderedDict`, see the docs for more details: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

**EDIT**
However, for Python 3.6+ dicts will be insertion ordered. See this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6) for more details, or read the related [PEP 468](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/)

Answer (score 0):

Use OrderedDict to retain the insertion order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
my_dict = OrderedDict(x=500, y=500, z=500)
min_s = min(my_dict) # 'x'
```

You can check that all values are the same by creating a set with the dict values and checking its length:

```
>>> len(set(my_dict.values())) == 1
True
```